# android - java.lang.SecurityException: Connection refused

Tags: android, smartcard

Im new to UICC and Secure Elements and I tried to do a simple android 
application using this tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/seek-for- 
android/wiki/UsingSmartCardAPI) to connect the Secure Elements. When I 
run the application it throw an java.lang.SecurityException: 
Connection refused !!!. PLease help. 
Thanks

code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          final String LOG_TAG = "HelloSmartcard";     
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
          LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); 
          layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

          Button button = new Button(this); 
          button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));     
          button.setText("Click Me"); 
          button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                try { 
                      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Retrieve available readers..."); 
                      Reader[] readers = seService.getReaders(); 
                      if (readers.length < 1) 
                         return;     
                      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create Session from the first reader..."); 
                      Session session = readers[0].openSession();     
                      Log.d(LOG_TAG, 
                      "Create logical channel within the session..."); 
                      Channel channel = session.openLogicalChannel(new 
byte[] { 
                      (byte) 0xD2, 0x76, 0x00, 0x01, 0x18, 0x00, 0x02, 
                      (byte) 0xFF, 0x49, 0x50, 0x25, (byte) 0x89, 
                      (byte) 0xC0, 0x01, (byte) 0x9B, 0x01 });     
                      //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Send HelloWorld APDU command"); 
                      byte[] respApdu = channel.transmit(new byte[] { 
                      (byte) 0x90, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });     
                      channel.close();     
                      // Parse response APDU and show text but remove SW1 SW2 first 
                      byte[] helloStr = new byte[respApdu.length - 2]; 
                      System.arraycopy(respApdu, 0, helloStr, 0, 
respApdu.length - 2); 
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, new 
String(helloStr),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                   } catch (Exception e) { 
                      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error occured:", e); 
                      return; 
                   } 
            } 
          }); 

          layout.addView(button); 
          setContentView(layout); 
          try { 
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "creating SEService object"); 
                seService = new SEService(this, this); 
              } catch (SecurityException e) { 
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Binding not allowed, uses-permission org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SMARTCARD?"); 
              } catch (Exception e) { 
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
              } 

    }
```

logcat

```
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691): Error occured:
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691): java.lang.SecurityException: Connection refused !!!
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SEService.checkForException(SEService.java:611)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SEService.openLogicalChannel(SEService.java:479)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session.openLogicalChannel(Session.java:143)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at com.gieseckedevrient.android.hellosmartcard.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
05-22 08:11:49.669: E/HelloSmartcard(6691):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gieseckedevrient.android.hellosmartcard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SMARTCARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <uses-library android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi" android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post logcat out put, not an image

Comment: can you post your manifest.xml file.

Comment: On which device with what Android ROM image are you running this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//Define the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SMARTCARD"/>
```

Comment: i have the smartcard permision already. Why i need internet.?

Comment: ya you dont need that. if you are not requesting to webservice.

Comment: no...i dont have access to webservice.. do u have any other way for me to connect to UICC sim...?

Comment: @chinna_82 he Android system runs on the application processor, thus has limited or no access to the SIM card. Communication with the SIM card is provided by the baseband processor over AT commands (e.g. AT+CPIN, AT+CRSM) defined by 3GPP 27.007 specification or through an proprietary IPC interface.

Comment: I am facing same issues. And also give permission, but still problem is there. Do you have solution... @PadmaKumar